# How to process standart html tags in xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have not practiced XML in over a year.
My question is, using the samples below, why my for-each statement is only printing the first paragraph.

If you are wanting to know why my XML is using standard HTML "p" tags that I am trying to put back into "p" tags in my XSL file: the reason is I am batch processing several long writer documents from a word processor into HTML files. There are thousands (maybe tens of thousands) of paragraph tags. I cannot output XML files in any format I can use or manipulate the way I want.

I can however save the HTML file with an XML extension and work with that. I have already converted a few other files, but not tried to for-each the

tags yet.

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>

<Library>
    <Books>
        <MyBooks>

            <my_favorite_book>
                <title>the title of my favorite book</title>
                <p>paragraph 1</p>
                <p>paragraph 2</p>
                <p>paragraph 3</p>
                <p>paragraph 4</p>
                <p>paragraph 5</p>
                <p>paragraph 6</p>
                <p>paragraph 7</p>
                <p>paragraph 8</p>
                <p>paragraph 9</p>
           </my_favorite_book>

        </MyBooks>
    </Books>
</Library>
```

My XSL file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

            <xsl:template match="/">

                <html>
                   <body>

                    <p align="center">
                        <span style="font-size: 5em;">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book/title" />
                            </b>
                        </span>
                        <br/>
                     </p>

                    <xsl:for-each select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="p" />
                        </p>
                    </xsl:for-each>

            </body>
        </html>


        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Web browser output (FireFox 54.0.1 (32-bit))

[image]

Comment: You've asked 8 questions over the course of nearly 3 years and [**accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) none.  Please accept those answers that have helped you.  If none of your 8 questions have received helpful answers, then please read [ask].   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, using the samples below, why my for-each statement is
>   only printing the first paragraph.

Because your `for-each`,

```
<xsl:for-each select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book">
```

is selecting the only `my_favorite_book`, and your `xsl:value-of`,

```
   <xsl:value-of select="p" />
```

is selecting all of `my_favority_book`'s children only to take the string value of the first such `p`,

```
   paragraph 1
```

The shortest fix to your program would be to loop over the paragraphs,

```
<xsl:for-each select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book/p">
```

and take the value-of each,

```
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
```

or, instead of looping with `xsl:for-each`, you might use `apply-templates` instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book/p">
```

if you come to have further pattern matching to do, or `copy-of` if you don't:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book/p">
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer in another Stack Overflow post that worked.

That is, to change the above code to the code below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Library/Books/MyBooks/my_favorite_book/p">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

Also, while looking at some other projects I did, and reading other posts here, I now recall that using the "template" methods yielded a smoother and more flexible result, so I am going to radically modify my XSL file tomorrow and leave an update here.

Comment: Why did you feel compelled to restate [**the answer that I've already provided you**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982218/290085) rather than simply [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) it per normal protocol here?

Comment: My apologies. I had found the answer myself only moments after I posted my question, and posted my own answer before the system posted yours. Just a matter of timing. Thank you for such a quick response anyhow.

Comment: My answer had been posted for ***19 minutes*** at the time you posted this -- not even close to a timing issue.  Rather than say "my appologies," you should just [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) my answer and delete what you posted later because it adds no value over what's already here.  You should also accept some of the other answers that have helped you in the past.  Accepting no answers for 8 questions asked over nearly 3 years shows a lack of understanding how this site works or a lack of appreciation for the answers you receive.

Comment: I see what you mean about how the site works. So, I need to delete my own answer so you can get points for answering the question?

Comment: No, you're free to add an answer to your own question, but you should only do so if you have something new to add about how you solved your problem that's not already covered by existing answers.  You're also free to upvote and accept answers as you wish, but the site works best when you reward good answers with upvotes and you accept answers that have helped you the most.  Thank you.